# Obtener datos con un CURL en una App de React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy haciendo la siguiente petición CURL a mí App de React JS que tengo en localhost

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http:localhost:3000 \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "123456"
  }'
```

Son dos CURL pero solo cambia el HEADER donde le pasare JSON o HTML.

```
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
```

o

```
--header 'content-type: application/html' \
```

Quiero saber como puedo interferir esta petición en una App de React y cuando la cabecera sea JSON devolver un JSON que yo tengo personalizado por ejemplo

```
{
  "name": "Administrador",
  "email": "admin@admin.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de la cabecera `Content-type` no se utiliza en peticiones para elegir el tipo de recurso a recibir.

- En **peticiones** (mensajes enviados desde el cliente al servidor), `Content-type` sirve para indicar el tipo contenido que se le está enviando al servidor.
- En **respuestas** (mensajes enviados desde el servidor al cliente), `Content-type` sirve para indicar el tipo de contenido que se está enviado al cliente.

Dicho eso, no quiere decir que no tengas forma de elegir el recurso a recibir, puedes habilitar diferentes URLs o diferentes parámetros para conseguir el mismo efecto, y no hacerlo a base de cabeceras. Ejemplos:

Por URLs:

- http://localhost:3000/json -> Devuelve json
- http://localhost:3000/html -> Devuelve html

Por parámetros:

- http://localhost:3000?type=json -> Devuelve json
- http://localhost:3000?type=html -> Devuelve html

SI lo haces por URLs tendrás que añadir las correspondientes rutas que redirijan a llos componentes que generan el JSON y al HTML respectivamente.

Si lo haces por parámetros, tendrás que extraer dichos parámetros desde el componente principal que estás accediendo desde `/` y discriminar por el valor del parámetro `type`.

Más información:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type
- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo he solucionado con una Lambda den Node, donde captura el Content-Type y si JSON sirvo un json y si es HTML sirvo la App de React como normalmente.